# Using global variables with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, global-variables, concurrent.futures

With following program with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor I am trying to make the worker process be able to modify the var dictionary in global scope. Then I want to be able to use that modified var dictionary.

```
from time import sleep
import concurrent.futures as cf

tasks = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

def my_worker(scan_task):
    global var
    print(scan_task)
    var[scan_task] = 0
    print(var)
    sleep(1)

var = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(my_worker, scan_task) for scan_task in tasks]
    cf.wait(futures)
    print("finished")
    print(var)
```

The worker process is able to modify it properly. However after processes finish their parts, when I try to print the var, I am receiving following output, var is an empty dictionary:

```
aaa
{'aaa': 0}
bbb
{'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 0}
ccc
{'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 0, 'ccc': 0}
finished
{}
```

How can I use the modified var dictionary in the main function after workers finish their parts?

And following is the intended output:

```
aaa
{'aaa': 0}
bbb
{'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 0}
ccc
{'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 0, 'ccc': 0}
finished
{'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 0, 'ccc': 0}
```

Comment: Remember that these are separate processes, with totally independent memory spaces.  Each process has its own copy of `tasks`.  You CAN use a `multiprocessing.Manager` to create dictionaries that are shared.  The multiprocessing module will use TCP/IP to send updates back and forth.  Or, you can use a `multiprocessing.queue` to send your results back to the originating process.

Answer (score 0):

Memory changes in a process are not seen by its parent process unless you've setup shared memory. You can't instantiate python objects in shared memory directly, so they need to be serialized and transferred to the parent for it to get a result.

With the workflow you show in the example, this is best done with `map`. `map`  sends data to the worker function and retrieves the function's result. Change your worker to return a value instead of trying to update `var`. And since you want a map of task value to result, `map` can be used with `zip` to build the resulting `dict`.

```
from time import sleep
import concurrent.futures as cf

tasks = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

def my_worker(scan_task):
    print("working on", scan_task)
    sleep(1)
    return scan_task

var = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        var = dict(zip(tasks, executor.map(my_worker, tasks)))
    print(var)
```